# Can't download artifacts from central maven repository

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am testing a simple maven project, which needs to download Jboss Java EE 7, but it fails to do that. The error message is:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:test:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-7.0:jar:1.0.3.Final in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

And the full pom.xml is below. What is causing this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>test_1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The artifact is there, but it is not a `jar` (the default), it is a `zip`. Moreover, it seems to have a classifier (`source-release`) attached. Provided that this is indeed the dependency you want, you need to specify your dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
  <type>zip</type>
  <classifier>source-release</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks. Why does it use a zip file and a classifier?

Comment: I really have no idea; you would have to ask JBoss about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using force download

```
mvn clean install -U
```

> -U means force update of dependencies.

Also artifacts are present [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/spec/jboss-javaee-7.0/1.0.3.Final/)

Comment: Just tried. The same thing, same error message. Strange.